# MediaWiki 1.25.2 upgrade script fails from 1.10

Tags: php, mysql, upgrade, mediawiki

I am trying to upgrade a mediawiki database from 1.10 to 1.23.10 (the same happens with 1.25.2). I have followed all the steps described in the MediaWiki upgrade page, but the script fails with the following error:

```
Updating indexes to 20031107 ...A database query error has occurred.
Query: ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS `links`
 DROP INDEX l_from,
 ADD INDEX l_from (l_from)

Function: DatabaseBase::sourceFile( patch-indexes.sql )
Error: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS `links`\x0A DROP INDEX l_from,\x0A ADD INDEX l_from (l_from)' at line 1 (localhost)

PHP Notice:  Uncommitted DB writes (transaction from DatabaseUpdater::doUpdates). in /home/max/newforum2/mediawiki-1.23.10/includes/db/Database.php on line 4147
```

I am using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 (cli) and MySQL 5.5.44.

Comment: Appears to be a bug with the updater. `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS` only works on PostgreSQL >=9.2. Should probably be reported somewhere. In the mean time you can try removing the `IF EXISTS` part in `/maintenance/archives/patch-indexes.sql`

Comment: Introduced with https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/rMW3d1abfb77d78d5c830cbed3bdea260b35151ab34 @TiiJ7 wanna file a patch? :) https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Git/Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

> *TiiJ7* said it already: ***The bug appears with the MediaWiki update script!***

#### Informations

- `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS` only works on PostgreSQL >=9.2.
- It's already reported to Wikimedia at [Phabricator](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/rMW3d1abfb77d78d5c830cbed3bdea260b35151ab34).

#### Repair the bug

> Try to remove the `IF EXISTS` code part in **`patch-indexes.sql`** file in *`/maintenance/archives`* folder!

From this:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS/*$wgDBprefix*/links
 DROP INDEX l_from,
 ADD INDEX l_from (l_from);

ALTER TABLE /*$wgDBprefix*/brokenlinks
 DROP INDEX bl_to,
 ADD INDEX bl_to (bL_to);

ALTER TABLE /*$wgDBprefix*/recentchanges
```

to this:

```
ALTER TABLE /*$wgDBprefix*/links
 DROP INDEX l_from,
 ADD INDEX l_from (l_from);

ALTER TABLE /*$wgDBprefix*/brokenlinks
 DROP INDEX bl_to,
 ADD INDEX bl_to (bL_to);

ALTER TABLE /*$wgDBprefix*/recentchanges
```